# Importing Login Configuration Text FIle In Python

Tags: python, file, import, configuration, automation

I'm new to Python, looked unsuccessfully for answers in previous posts. Hoping you can help me.

I'm trying to use a script I copied off of this [blog post](https://qxf2.com/blog/ssh-using-python-paramiko/).

Said script automates the process of starting SSH sessions on a given remote system and running commands on that system.

It imports a `configuration file`, from the import statement below I assume named `conf`, that supplies the script with login credentials, file paths, etc.

```
from conf import ssh_conf as conf_file
```

My issue is I am not sure how the conf file is formatted and it wasn't provided in the blog post. From the import statement I assume the file is named `conf.py` and the it has `sections`, one of them named `ssh_conf`

Can anyone describe how was that file formatted?

Gratefully,

A Python Newbie.

Answer (score 0):

There are not really sections like that.

If `conf.py` was a file, then this *could* be made to work, by making ssh_conf a `class` within `conf.py`:

```
class ssh_conf():
    HOST="www.example.com"
```

But that's kind of nasty and feels like pointless abuse of classes.

My guess is that `conf` is actually a **package**. That is to say, a directory called `conf` containing a (empty) file called `__init__.py` and a number of other files, any of which can be imported from `conf`. One of these files would be called `ssh_conf.py` and that would contain things like:

```
HOST="www.example.com"
```

The overall structure looks like:

```
MyProject/
|-- my_application.py
`-- conf/
    |-- __init__.py
    `-- ssh_conf.py
```

If you aren't familiar with packages, [the official documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html) is a good place to start.